# How can I set a file located in the Roaming Folder as an Environment Variable?

Tags: windows, python, environment-variables

I have installed [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/install) on my Windows. The `jupyter.exe` command looks like stored in `C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts`.

```
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts>dir
 Volume in drive C is XXXX
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX

 Directory of C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts

27/04/2023  11:08    <DIR>          .
27/04/2023  11:08    <DIR>          ..
21/03/2023  13:23           108.427 ipython.exe
21/03/2023  13:23           108.427 ipython3.exe
27/04/2023  11:08           108.421 jupyter-console.exe
21/03/2023  13:23           108.426 jupyter-kernel.exe
21/03/2023  13:23           108.464 jupyter-kernelspec.exe
21/03/2023  13:23           108.422 jupyter-migrate.exe
27/04/2023  11:08           102.281 jupyter-qtconsole.exe
21/03/2023  13:23           108.443 jupyter-run.exe
21/03/2023  13:23           108.427 jupyter-troubleshoot.exe
21/03/2023  13:23           108.422 jupyter.exe
21/03/2023  13:23           108.418 pygmentize.exe
21/03/2023  13:23            27.225 pywin32_postinstall.py
21/03/2023  13:23             3.546 pywin32_testall.py
27/04/2023  11:08           108.415 qtpy.exe
21/03/2023  13:23    <DIR>          __pycache__
              14 File(s)      1.325.764 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  11.283.652.608 bytes free
```

I have set `jupiter.exe` in Environment Variables but still gives me the error `'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. I have tried close & reopen the command prompt and restarting the Windows but still didn't work.

```
C:\Users\XXXX>jupyter
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image: env]

Does it mean setting up an application (where located in Roaming Folder) on Environment Variables does not work? How to solve that?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the PATH?

Comment: @Gantendo What PATH did you mean?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YvpRgLh.png & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

Comment: @Gantendo I did

Comment: Yeah thats the executable, the PATH requires the folder where it will search for the executable. So delete the `jupyter.exe` part

Comment: Still doesn't work. Is that because `AppData` folder is hidden?

Comment: In my screenshot for example Python is also installed in AppData and it works fine

Comment: Which steps have you followed to install it? You can just run it in any browser https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/start/index.html#id4

Comment: Nice references to run it from the browser 

Answer (score 1):

> I have set `jupiter.exe` in Environment Variables but still gives me the error `'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

If you're editing the `PATH` variable specifically, its values are always *directories,* not individual files. The system would only find "jupyter.exe" through PATH if you had the entire `Python310\Scripts` directory listed there.

(Other variables are not used by the system *at all* when searching for executables, unless explicitly referenced using the shell's "variable expansion" syntax. For example, a variable *named* `jupyter` would only be expanded if you typed `%jupyter%` in Cmd or `$env:jupyter` in PowerShell, but *not* if you just typed `jupyter`.)

Comment: Still doesn't work with defining just `...\Python310\Scripts`

Comment: @Jordy Rebooting *may* be necessary

Comment: Ok, I will try it